# The Model in GWTP - raising changed events

Tags: java, gwt, model, mvp, gwt-platform

We are developing a new application using GWTP (GWT 2.4).

There is quite a lot of articles regarding the presenter-view way of design - responsibilities of each component, communication between them - but less focus is given to the model component.

In our application, we use the Actions of GWTP and receive from the server some DTO, which we mostly do CRUD on.
We have some UI-Entity wrapper of each DTO. This UI-Entity holds  all required meta-data for viewing it (what properties it has, their display name etc.) and provides set/get for all properties.

We wonder how to propagate model-changed events.
As I see it, there are two ways:

1. The UI-Entity raises events.
2. The Action raises events, on callback from server.

I think that the big difference between the two methods is that the first option makes the model "live" - if user is doing changes, they are reflected in the application even if not sent to server. In the second option, the application will be aware of data changed events only when data was actually changed in server.

As I see it - usually you need both approaches, but I cannot find examples supporting the first approach: usually when the first approach is considered - it states that it is more an MVC design than an MVP.

What do you think?
Any recommendations?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you should be able to use a propertychangeevent with some kind of listeners registered, generally, if you had a textfield, there would be a property change listener on that field, and then whenever the field changed, some event would get fired onto the bus.  Naturally you still need to bind from the ui to model object (I suggest Gwittir, it does all of this very nicely).

The second problem is similar, the server makes a callback through whatever means you have in place, and then that should trigger an event on the bus that says "field whatever has a new value!!!", and at that point the individual fields (which should be registered and listening) can decide whether or not to listen to that event and react appropriately.

So, basically, your fields should be listening to the bus, and whenever the model changes, either from the server or ui side, there should be a message sent to the bus so any interested listeners can handle that change. This decouples the design and handles both cases.and simplifies complex widget level interactions.

I don't think this setup violates MVP in any meaningful way, to be a purest (as I frame MVP) you could have your presenter listening to the bus and then tell the view to change, but to me that seems like a pointless layer of abstraction, coupling, and source for bugs and more work later.

Let me know if that's an answer to the wrong question, I will edit if I'm not understanding the subtlety of the problem.